# .float() in pytorch changes the value of an int

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

```
import torch
torch.set_printoptions(precision=1, sci_mode=False)

numeric_seq_id = 2021080918959999952

t = torch.tensor(numeric_seq_id)
tt = torch.tensor(numeric_seq_id).float() # !!!

print(t, tt)
```

output is

```
tensor(2021080918959999952) tensor(2021080905052848128.)
```

We could see that `tt`'s value is changed after `.float()` transform.

Why is here such a difference on the value?

---

ps. pytorch's version = `1.10.1`

python's version = `3.8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not `pytorch` specific, but an artifact of how floats (or doubles) are represented in memory (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate) for more details), which we can also see in `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

np_int = np.int64(2021080918959999952)
np_float = np.float32(2021080918959999952)
np_double = np.float64(2021080918959999952)

print(np_int, int(np_float), int(np_double))
```

Output:

```
2021080918959999952 2021080905052848128 2021080918960000000
```